# Uses of excluded middle on a conjecture that can be rewritten constructively with this trick

Tags: soft-question, constructive-mathematics, conjectures

An interesting proof technique is to use the law of excluded middle on a conjecture. There are proofs [using LEM on the Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Excluded_middle) for example.

Constructively this is disallowed (if you can constructively prove LEM for an open problem, it's no longer an open problem!), but there is something equivalent.

Let's say the theorem $T$ we want to prove is of the form $\forall t. P(t) \implies Q(t)$, and $C$ is a related conjecture. We can non-constructively prove $T$ by first proving the following two lemmas:

1. $\forall t. (\lnot C \land P(t)) \implies Q(t)$
2. $\forall t. (C \land P(t)) \implies Q(t)$

or *equivalently* we can constructively prove $T$ by first constructively proving the following two lemmas*:

3. $\forall t. P(t) \implies (Q(t) \lor C)$
4. $\forall t. (C \land P(t)) \implies Q(t)$

This is constructive because proof by cases is constructively valid. Assuming $P(t)$, we can derive $Q(t)$ in both cases.

**My question**: are there any non-toy examples of theorems proven by LEM on a conjecture that can be rewritten constructively with this trick? That is, the classical proof is split into lemmas 1 and 2, but the proofs of those lemmas be constructively rewritten into proofs for lemmas 3 and 4.

---

<sub>* In theory, lemma 3 also gives a new way to look for proofs of $C$. For every known example of $t$ that satisfies $P(t)$, run it through lemma 3 and see whether it proves $Q(t)$ or proves $C$.** But, I'm guessing in practice every $t$ you try will result in the $Q(t)$ case. You just use $C$ as an "escape valve" for any weird edge cases you think are impossible but which you do not know how to rule out (but which lead to $C$ for some reason).</sub>

<sub>** More formally, given a formal proof in a constructive theory of $\exists t. P(t)$, you can find a proof of $C \lor \exists t. Q(t)$ from lemma 3. By the [disjunction property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties), the constructive theory either proves $C$ or proves $\exists t. Q(t)$. Typically, it will be easy to see which one and extract it from the proof of $C \lor \exists t. Q(t)$ we have on hand. If it turns out to be a proof of $C$, we have proven the conjecture. If not, start again with a different proof of $\exists t. P(t)$. For example, if $P(t)$ is "$t$ is a prime number", there is a different proof of $\exists t. P(t)$ for each prime number.</sub>

Comment: How many examples are there of statements proven using LEM applied to a conjecture in the first place? I feel like I haven't heard of any besides the famous Riemann hypothesis examples.

Comment: Another thing that should be noted is that constructive theories are often $\Pi^0_2$-conservative over their classical counterpart (e.g., $\mathsf{HA}$ over $\mathsf{PA}$ and $\mathsf{IZF}$ over $\mathsf{ZFC}$). Most theorems in number theory are going to fall under this. In particular, I expect that of the RH-LEM examples on Wikipedia, Littlewood's theorem and the growth of Euler's totient are equivalent to $\Pi^0_2$ sentences. I suspect Gauss's class number conjecture is too, but I don't know enough analytic number theory.

Comment: You have two sets of lemmas numbered 1 and 2. Which ones are you asking about/

Comment: @AndrejBauer sorry for the ambiguity, I renumbered them.

Comment: @JamesHanson I think my trick is closely related to the Friedman translation used to prove $\Pi^0_2$ translation now that I look at it. I guess even closer would be to use $\forall t. ((C \implies Q(t)) \land P(t))  \implies Q(t)$ for lemma 3. 

Comment: Unfortunately your (*) shows the problem with this idea: a constructive proof of a disjunction typically goes via a proof of one or other case.

Comment: @PaulTaylor not necessarily, they can also come from other disjunctions. For example, $P(t)$ might contain a disjunction. And things having to do with natural numbers are often decidable (such as whether a number is prime or not) which leads to disjunctions.